# Solr: How to search multiple fields

Tags: c#, solr, solrnet, edismax

I am using solrnet. I have a title and Description fields. I need to search both fields simultaneously. How do I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Jayendra's answer is correct, but if you want to do this without aggregating data in a single field at index-time (copyFields) and want to do it at query-time instead using the standard handler instead of dismax, in SolrNet you can do:

```
var query = Query.Field("title").Is(mytitle) || Query.Field("Description").Is(mydescription);
var results = solr.Query(query);
```

See [query operators](http://code.google.com/p/solrnet/wiki/Querying#Query_operators) and [DSL](http://code.google.com/p/solrnet/wiki/DSL) for more information.

Comment: wow..very interesting. When someone types "rocket scientist" in the query box then I pass this to solrnet. What do I put for "mytitle" and "mydescription"?

Comment: @Luke101 : they're the same... just sample variables representing user input. E.g. mytitle = mydescription = Request.QueryString["q"];

Comment: Thank you..I went ahead and implemented this solution.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a standard request handler -
Create a new field title_description and copy the title and description field to this field.
Use that field as the default search field.

```
<defaultSearchField>title_description</defaultSearchField>
```

Query q fired with search on the default search field -

```
q=bank
```

OR

If you can use dismax or edismax query parser, you can define a new request handler.
Define the query fields as qf.

```
<requestHandler name="dismax" class="solr.SearchHandler">
   <lst name="defaults">
     <str name="echoParams">explicit</str>
     <!-- Query settings -->
     <str name="defType">edismax</str>
     <str name="qf">
        title description
     </str>
     <str name="q.alt">*:*</str>
     <str name="rows">10</str>
     <str name="fl">*,score</str>
   </lst>
</requestHandler>
```

Query - pass the dismax as the qt parameter which would search on the title and description fields

```
q=bank&qt=dismax
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try to pass the string array that contains multiple field names and search text in the below method. I will return the solrnet query for search with multiple filed name with OR condition.

```
public ISolrQuery BuildQuery(string[] SearchFields, string SearchText)
    {

        AbstractSolrQuery firstQuery = new SolrQueryByField(SearchFields[0], SearchText) { Quoted = false };
        for (var i = 1; i < SearchFields.Length; i++)
        {
            firstQuery = firstQuery || new SolrQueryByField(SearchFields[i], SearchText) { Quoted = false };
        }

        return firstQuery;
    }
```